# Is there a way to add Trello "members" to a list, without them being registered?

Tags: trello

I'd like to add someone else to my Trello tasks, for my own info, without actually having to create an account for them.

Essentially, I want to be able to give, say 'Fred' a picture, and be able to add Fred to a card, without having to:

1. get them to pass on their email details to Trello (and have yet another password to track)
2. get them to set up a Gravatar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suppose a workaround with pictorial representation would be to:

1. invent a new email address, via an [email address alias](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=12096) such as my_google_account+fred_trello@mydomain.com...
2. create a Gravatar for that email alias address.

Comment: This worked, with a test email account created using [fastmail plus addressing](http://www.fastmail.fm/help/features_plus_addressing_and_subdomain_addressing.html), and then creating a Gravatar.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is not a way to do this.  A workaround would be to do something with card name whereby you say "FRED: fix leaky faucet".

Comment: Thanks. It's really the easy-to-interpret pictorial representation that I'm after.

Answer (score 3):

Another workaround, that gives a visual representation, is to use the Label facility. This draws a narrow coloured line along the top of the Card.

Edit your Board's Preferences, and in the Labels section, click on a label name (e.g. "Red (default)" and type in the new name, e.g. Fred - and the Save.

Then, when hovering over a Card, hit the letter L, and click on the chosen Label (e.g. Fred) to assign it to a card.

At the least this gives a visual reminder of the meaning of each colour, when you show the available labels.

(It doesn't, however, allow you to hit the letter Q, to filter and show only your labels.)