# Can I create Members who do not have valid email addresses

Tags: trello

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to add Trello “members” to a list, without them being registered?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18976/is-there-a-way-to-add-trello-members-to-a-list-without-them-being-registered)

I would like to use Trello to track tasks for Users who do not have email accounts.  Can I do this?

Comment: No, I don't believe it is.

However, see [this similar question](http://WebApps.StackExchange.com/questions/18976/is-there-a-way-to-add-trello-members-to-a-list-without-them-being-registered/18982#18982) for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

An email address is required for signup. It helps prevent spam accounts, provides easy password recovery, and allows for email notifications.

Creating virtual or token users is not currently possible, either.